# Is there a fake way to drive a matrix keyboard (to use a typewriter as line-printer)

Tags: arduino, multiplexer, keyboard

I recently found a `Brother AX-425 typewriter`, I want to be able to control it via a computer.

[image: Brother AX-425 typewriter]

Its internal electronic seems pretty simple, it's a 8*8 matrix keyboard that is connected to an unknown Panasonic IC (`lc 1176 c` : i didn't find any datasheet for it) that drive the different motors.

I'd like to know if i could use a electronic circuit to drive the keyboard and make him think that i'm typing ?

I've got like 2 idea but i'm new and not really sure :

- **The brute-force way** : I buy 16 relays to simulate the 8*8 matrix that controls the typewriter instead of the keyboard, I use and Arduino to drive those.
  I'm pretty sure it will work, but i'm not sure about making this circuit, even if it could make a cool-looking vintage style circuit.
- **The electrical engineer way** : I noticed that there is a +0.2V difference between the rows and columns of the matrix and a sub mA current passing when a key make contact
  (I only used a multimeter to mesure this, maybe i could try using a logic analyser made with an Arduino.

  So I tough about connecting the 8 rows to an 8 bits multiplexer and the output to the collectors of 8 transistors, using that i'll be able to select a row and a colulmn via my Arduino and stimulate a key press.

  But the voltage difference seems low that my circuit could just drop the 0.2V and thus making it not working.

Sort of related topic :

- They told him to user multiplexers but the voltage differnce is 5V :
  [Typewriter keyboard matrix control with Arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202591/typewriter-keyboard-matrix-control-with-arduino)

I'm looking forward to your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: I think I wrote that to a similar question (can't find it, sadly), but: it's probably way easier to directly interface to the letters-producing circuitry than to the keyboard-scanning circuitry.

Comment: You can probably use CMOS analog switches to drive the keys.  I once did the same for the 1st Sears calculator for an exercise machine to count steps or count down calories per step and interface the display to 4 huge LEDs 7seg display.

Comment: If it is an 8x8 matrix, surely you would only need 16 relays for your brute force method.

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe, but from my point of view it seemed to me simpler to simulate a closed circuit than to analyse and reproduce the letters-producing circuitry

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I didn't know the existence of CMOS analog switches, so if I get it right i'll need to use 16 of them ?

Comment: @HandyHowie oh, yes, right, I'll edit it

Comment: Seeing only 0.2 V on multimeter display is likely related to scanning of the matrix (a, more-or-less, average over scanning duty-cycle per line), not the "high" signal for the controller. I believe, you can safely assume the high signal voltage will be around 5 V (minus some diode drop possibly) or more.

Comment: @Martin it's in fact around like 4.6V from row to GND and 4.4V from columns to GND

Comment: @Ant0ine64 I've taken two quite different devices and turned typewriters into printers. That one doesn't look difficult, either, though each presents their own issues. In both cases, it took me time at first scoping out details prior to design and coding. In both cases, the result worked the first time I powered them. The early study is vital to a successful result. One was the model 85 IBM electronic typewriter for example.

Comment: 4016, 4066 hundreds of others are CMOS switches

Comment: Thank you all for your knowledge @jonk i'm going to try out and eventually post an update if i have useful things to share !

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 thanks, i'm gonna get some of these

Comment: @Ant0ine64 I didn't really say much except that you need to do some work first and that it probably can be done! I usually just open up the device and start looking around it, at first. Just to figure out how they laid things out. Hopefully, I find some simplifying things. (Like a nice ribbon cable going from the keyboard area to some board?) Then I can see a way to figure things out more easily. Best wishes!

Comment: @jonk yes ! that what I've already done, I also soldered pins to the connector tu use as a breakout for tests and then prototype. Thank to all the answers and what I think of it, I have a pretty good idea of what I'm going to do.

Comment: @Ant0ine64 Thanks so much for letting me know things are moving nicely forward!! Appreciated!